# how to not display the coma sign for integers in excel

Tags: excel

OKAY, I have not worked with Excel since the last millennium, so I am not fresh.
In German Excel we have "," as float delimiter.

To cut a long story short ... this is what I want:

```
one and a half pixel is:  1,5 px
one pixel            is:    1 px
ten pixel            is:   10 px
half of a  pixel     is:  0,5 px
```

So I then tried to set up a custom number format with which I can then display the numbers as pixels

```
####0,#### px
```

The numbers then look like this:

```
one and a half pixel is:  1,5 px
one pixel            is:   1, px
ten pixel            is:  10, px
half of a  pixel     is:  0,5 px
```

Then I tried this

```
####0,0#### px
```

The numbers then look like this:

```
one and a half pixel is:  1,5 px
one pixel            is:  1,0 px
ten pixel            is: 10,0 px
half of a  pixel     is:  0,5 px
```

But I don't want to draw a coma with integers , is there a solution?

Comment: I think you still need to use the dot as the decimal placeholder in the format string, even though the decimal separator will appear as a comma in the output. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Comment: Can you simply try formatting cell as `0px`

Comment: @Harun24HR, that would make `1,5 px` into `2 px` and `0,5 px` into `1 px`.

Comment: @JvdV I am writing from Mobile and not tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just use the german equivalent of:

`General px`

[image]

In the picture above I used the Dutch equivalent: `Standaard px`. And yes, here too, the decimal comma is used as per my locale settings.